# Converting tidy select arguments to character vector

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

I'm struggling to convert tidy select style function arguments to a character vector.

```r
f <- function(d, cols1, cols2) {
  <do something useful with d>
  <some magic>
}
f(iris, c(Sepal.Length, Species), Petal.Width)
# [1] "Sepal.Length" "Species" "Petal.Width"
```

Here's a motivating example.

Let's say I have a function which creates two `data.frame`s and joins them. One of the `data.frame`s is long to compute, so I would like to have an option to provide a precomputed data.frame.

Here I am using tidy evaluation using embrace. See a minimal example:

```r
my_func <- function(df, cols1, cols2, df2=NULL) {
  df1 <- df %>%
    do_something(across({{cols1}})

  if (!is.null(df2) {
    # 1. here I would like to check column names of df2
  } else {
    df2 <- df %>%
      do_something_very_slow(across({{cols2}})
  }

  # 2. here I would like to provide by=c(cols1, cols2)
  full_join(df1, df2)
}

# I am using tidy select to pass column names to the function.
result <- my_func(df, c(a, b), c)
```

Now here are two improvements I would like to make to this code.

1. In #1 I would like to verify that precomputed_df has all the columns it needs (namely: a, b, and c). The straightforward approach would be to convert c(col1, col2) to a character vector. But of course this will through an error. Other alternatives I see is trying to `select()` with `tryCatch()`, but this looks rather ugly.
2. In #2 `full_join()` will through a message "joining by columns XXX". The only way to avoid this is to provide an explicit character vector of column names `by=c('a', 'b', 'c')`. But for that I need a character vector again. Ugly work-arounds would be `intersect(names(df1), names(df2))` or `suppressMessages()`. This might work when one is sure that there are no extra columns in df1 and df2. Another rather ugly approach is to use `names(select(df1, c({{cols1}}, {{cols2}}))`.

Is there a more elegant way to convert `cols1` and `cols2` to a character vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into [tidyselect documentation](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/articles/tidyselect.html):

```r
f <- function(d, cols1, cols2) {
  <do something useful with d>
  cols1_c <- tidyselect::eval_select(rlang::enquo(cols1), d)
  cols2_c <- tidyselect::eval_select(rlang::enquo(cols2), d)
  unique(names(d)[c(cols1_c, cols2_c)])
}

f(iris, c(Sepal.Length, Species), Petal.Width)
# [1] "Sepal.Length" "Species"      "Petal.Width"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand your question but the way to take a character vector in tidyselect context is with `all_of()`:

```r
across(all_of(cols1))
```

Comment: Note that you can still take the columns with `{{` as you have. Then your caller would be the one that has to use `all_of()` to pass a character vector. This is the most flexible solution.

Comment: So if I understand your suggestion correctly, the caller of my_func should first encode variables as a character vector and then use my_func(df, all_of(char_vector)). This of course defeats the purpose of using tidy select. The idea is to be able to call my_func(df, c(var1, var2), c(var3, var4)). And then to be able to get c("var1", "var2") inside the function.

Comment: This was not my suggestion. I don't think I understand your problem either but it looks like you've found a solution.